# Cannot find Certificate - Azure .NET Core App

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

When I run my webapp from Azure, I'm getting an exception saying that it cannot find my certificate.

1. I have configured KeyVault to store my secrets and I've uploaded my private key certificate to my TLS/SSL settings.
2. In Azure Active Directory I'v registered my app which has the same Thumbprint as my private key certificate.
3. In my web app's configuration, I've added "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES" = "*", and "KeyVault:Vault"="meiwebapivault"
4. Then in code, my Program.cs handles finding the certificate. 
   However this is where it fails.

Any idea what steps I'm missing or why this is failing?

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b21EQvfjvHc&list=LLbGcLUIqnMVaE_WB28_w6YA&index=10&t=871s).

[image: KeyVault - Secrets]

[image: Azure Active Directory - App Registration]

[image: Uploaded certificate]

[image: webApp TSL/SSL Settings - private certificate]

[image: Configuration - App Settings]

```cs
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
                {
                    var root = builder.Build();
                    var vaultName = root["KeyVault:Vault"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vaultName))
                    {
                        builder.AddAzureKeyVault($"https://{vaultName}.vault.azure.net/",
                            root["KeyVault:ClientId"],
                            GetCertificate(root["KeyVault:Thumbprint"]),
                            new PrefixKeyVaultSecretManager("WebApi"));
                    }
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });

        private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string thumbprint)
        {
            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            try
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                var certificateCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, true);

                if (certificateCollection.Count == 0)
                    throw new Exception("Certificate is not installed"); //<------------- FAILS HERE

                return certificateCollection[0];
            }
            finally
            {
                store.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

```json
{
  "KeyVault": {
    "Vault": "",
    "ClientId": "6ac#####-####-####-####-######ffe96",
    "Thumbprint": "4EC2C##############################4507C"
  },
```

```cs
public class PrefixKeyVaultSecretManager : IKeyVaultSecretManager
    {
        private readonly string _prefix;

        public PrefixKeyVaultSecretManager(string prefix)
        {
            _prefix = $"{prefix}-";
        }
        public string GetKey(SecretBundle secret)
        {
            return secret.SecretIdentifier.Name.Substring(_prefix.Length)
                .Replace("--", ConfigurationPath.KeyDelimiter);
        }

        public bool Load(SecretItem secret)
        {
            return secret.Identifier.Name.StartsWith(_prefix);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);`? Why do you read from the personal store of that user? There should be nothing there.

Comment: I do see my certificates when I debug and run locally. I discovered the issue is that the certificate isn't valid. I changed the last parameter to ```false``` and it works. But still in Azure I get an error saying it cannot find my connection string, which is stored as a secret in the KeyVault

Comment: "Debug and run locally" is completely different from deployed to Azure App Service, so your code cannot assume the personal store exists on Azure nor it contains the same kind of certificate. You shouldn't expect anyone to watch a 30-minute video and then answer your question either.

Comment: It is deployed and that's 's where it's not working. I ran it locally to troubleshoot. I uploaded the certificate in Azure and figured it is stored in that store. The video was simply for reference as to what my approach was. I wasn't expecting anyone to have to watch the entire thing...

Comment: @LexLi Why the downvote? I'm just asking for help... How would you like me to ask this question?

Comment: You might try to share the whole project somewhere so others might review what exactly you are trying to do and what can be wrong. Merely the snippets above are not helpful. Like I commented initially, some lines are clearly invalid for Azure App Service. But again, that still requires too much time for someone to help. You should try to divide and conquer. Cut your big tasks to small steps and implement them using Azure API gradually, so that you can debug/test each steps separately. For a small step, you probably find tons of existing threads here.

Answer (score 1):

My setup was correct. I just needed to change this one line from

```cs
var certificateCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, true);
```

to

```cs
var certificateCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
```